# Chosen Drop-down: Implement non-exact search where each word will be invidualy searched

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a code in the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jHvmg/295/

where i have a dropdown which is enabled using chosen-plugin

```
<select id="drp_menu">
    <option value="01 - AU -Bingo Campaign1">01 - AU -Bingo Campaign1</option>
    <option value="02 - BR-Bingo  Campaign2">02 - BR-Bingo  Campaign2</option>
    <option value="03 - CA-Bingo  Campaign3">03 - CA- Bingo Campaign3</option>
    <option value="04- US - Bingo  Campaign4">04- US - Bingo  Campaign4</option>
</select>
```

If I type (bingo) or (ingo) or (ing) in the searchbox, then it displays the filtered list.

If i type (- AU -Bingo) in the searchbox, then it displays the option 1

But if I type (au bingo) it states "No results"

That's because there is no exact occurence of (au bingo) in the option.

But i want to search the option which has both (au) and (bingo) in the option.

Some sort of non-exact search..

How can i achieve this

Comment: You have to update chosen.js to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here your question is about, **fuzzy search** in Chosen Jquery plugin. And my answer is:

Such feature still does not found the way into chosen's core. I have referred
[**Issues with Chosen fuzzy search**](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/858)

Still, you can Try out the fork including this feature: [**Chosen new Version**](https://github.com/eliasdorneles/chosen).

Of course, I didn't test it and relay on their talk.

Comment: hi @Saswat, I searched a lot for it and here is what solution i got! ;)

Comment: As I'hv mentioned in my answer... It's referred from their talk.